# Calculating the covariance of a given random vector in the unit square

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Lets say there exists a random vector $(X,Y)$ evenly distributed in the unit square $[0,1]^2$. Now lets introduce the following two new random variables $U=min(X,Y)$ and $V=max(X,Y)$, what is the value of $Cov(U,V)$.

I have an idea of what I should, use directly the definition of the covariance,

$Cov(U,V)=EUV-EUEV = EXY-EUEV=EXEY-EUEV=\frac{1}{4}-EUEV$

But the real problem is I have no idea how to get the density functions of $X$ and $Y$. If anybody has a hint or an idea it would be great.

Comment: What is the probability that both $X$ and $Y$ are less then a given value $c, 0 \le c \le 1$: $P(X < c, Y < c) = $?. If you can answer this, use the result to find $P(V < c)$.

Comment: I know how to calculate $V$ and $U$ if I have $X,Y$, the problem I have is how to actually find the density function of $X and Y$ separately (should be the easiest part for some reason can't actually get it).

Comment: **evenly distributed in the unit square** gives you the density function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$ U = \min(X,Y) = \begin{cases}
X & ,~ \text{in the upper triangle of the unit square} \\
Y & ,~ \text{in lower triangle}
\end{cases} $$
With the upper triangle region being the first integral (and the lower region being the 2nd integral), 
\begin{align}
E[U] &= \int_{y = 0}^1 \left[ \int_{x = 0}^y 1\cdot x\, \mathrm{d}x \right]\, \mathrm{d}y + \int_{x = 0}^1 \left[ \int_{y = 0}^x 1\cdot y\, \mathrm{d}y \right]\, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{y = 0}^1  \frac{y^2}2\, \mathrm{d}y + \int_{x = 0}^1  \frac{x^2}2\, \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \frac13
\end{align}
Similarly, for $V = \max(X,Y)$, we have
\begin{align}
E[V] &= \int_{y = 0}^1 \left[ \int_{x = 0}^y 1\cdot \color{magenta}{y}\, \mathrm{d}x \right]\, \mathrm{d}y + \int_{x = 0}^1 \left[ \int_{y = 0}^x 1\cdot \color{magenta}{x}\, \mathrm{d}y \right]\, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{y = 0}^1  y^2\, \mathrm{d}y + \int_{x = 0}^1  x^2\, \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \frac23
\end{align}
Let me know if you need anything clarified.

Comment: thank you! now i understand my mistake